# Убрать атрибуты из html-тега с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

У меня такая проблема. Удаляю все атрибуты тегов HTML, но при выводе добавляются слеши, которые не нужны.

Вот код:

```
function Translate() {
   var a;
   a = document.forms["form1"].txtar1.value ;
   var b = RegExp("<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?>","gi"); 
   var c = RegExp("<$1>");
   a = a.replace(b,c);
        
   T2.value  = a; 
}
```

Ввожу `<p class="par"> Параграф  </p>`.

Получаю `/<p>/ Параграф  </p>`.

Помогите, плиз.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `removeTagAttributes` принимает в качестве параметра строку и убирает все HTML-аттрибуты, используя регулярные выражения.

```js
var removeTagAttributes = function(string) {
  return string.replace(/<([\S]*)[^>]*>/gi,'<$1>');
};

var result = removeTagAttributes('<p class="par">Параграф</p>');

document.write(result);
```

В регулярном выражении использован ключ `\S` — любой «непробельный» символ: всё, кроме пробелов, табуляций, переносов строк и т.д.

После этого вам остаётся только натравить эту функцию на вашу переменную `a`:

```
function Translate() {
   var a = document.forms["form1"].txtar1.value;
   T2.value = removeTagAttributes(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
function translate(str) {
    return str.replace(/(<[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9 "'=]*(>)/gi, '$1$2');
}
T2.value = translate(document.forms["form1"].txtar1.value);
```